# Not able to pass value properly

Tags: c

Newbie here. In this program I was trying to make a function named `bitcount` where I would count bits, where I will the get value from `main` function but its throwing some garbage value when compiled.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,n;
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d", a);
    n = bitcount(a);
    printf("the count is %d",n);
    return 0;
}

int bitcount(unsigned x)
{
    int i,n;
    for(i = 0; x != 0; x >>= 1)
        if(x & 01)
    n++;
    return n;
}
```

And also why can't we simply use `(x & 1)` in place of `(x & 01)`.

Comment: It's supposed to be `n = bitcount(a);`. And you certainly can use `x & 1`.

Comment: Actually i was missing "&" in scanf due to which garbage value was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

you have not store the value after calling the func `bitcount`add  `n = bitcount(a);` to store output in n.
and also use `&` when you are tring to take input with `scanf`. and intialize the value of `n = 0` in `bitcount` func. and also you can use `if(x& 1)` it is also valid

try this one:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<stdio.h>

int bitcount (unsigned x){

  int i, n;
  n=0; // initialize with 0 . update your code for initialization  here

  for (i = 0; x != 0; x >>= 1)

    if (x & 01)

      n++;

  return n;

}

int main () {

  int a, n;

  printf("Enter a number");

  scanf("%d",&a); // need to use address to store a value. and &a is the address for this a integer

  n = bitcount(a); // store the return value from bitcount func

  printf("the count is %d\n", n);

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

C stores garbage values in variables that have been declared, but yet to be assigned a value. You are not storing the value returned by `bitcount()`, resulting in garbage value.

```
printf("the count is %d", bitcount(a));
```

OR

```
n = bitcount(a);
printf("the count is %d", n);
```